# cannot Upload and Load images in Firebase Storage in Android studio if mobile data connection is used

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, picasso

Android 10 cannot Upload and Load images in Firebase Storage in Android studio. In android 9 or lower and 11 it works Fine. if my phone is in data connection, it wont load or upload image but if it is connected with Wifi it works. how can i solved this problem?
Any suggestions?

LogCat: 2021-04-15 21:38:51.089 8635-8657/? E/Gallery: [1657/         BeamManager] BeamManager : setBeamUris > can't load nfcadapter

```
private void getUserInformation(){
    databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>2){
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("firstname")) {
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue().toString();
                    nameEditext.setText(fullname);
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("lastname")) {
                    String lastname = dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue().toString();
                    ln.setText(lastname);
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("middlename")) {
                    String middlename = dataSnapshot.child("middlename").getValue().toString();
                    mn.setText(middlename);
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("address")) {
                    String ad = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                    address.setText(ad);
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("phone")) {
                    String phone = dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    phoneEditxt.setText(phone);
                }
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("plate_no")) {
                        String plate = dataSnapshot.child("plate_no").getValue().toString();
                        plate_noEditext.setText(plate);
                }

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")){
                    String image =dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                            .into(profileImage);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}



private void uploadImage() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Setting Accounts Info");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...saving your account..");
    progressDialog.show();
    final StorageReference ref = storageProfilePicRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+ ".jpg");

    final UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageUri);
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadurl= (Uri) task.getResult();
                        myurl=downloadurl.toString();
                        HashMap<String,Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("uid",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        userMap.put("firstname",nameEditext.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("phone",phoneEditxt.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("lastname",ln.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("middlename",mn.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("address",address.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("image",myurl);
                        userMap.put("plate_no",plate_noEditext.getText().toString());
                        //new Async().execute();
                        
databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                      //  finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
           double prencetage_=(snapshot.getBytesTransferred()*100.0)/ snapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading "+String.format("%.2f", prencetage_) + "%");
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/passenger"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/passenger"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">

        <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
</application>
```

[Image view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGah1Wahm_60xx9dEAK4MTtCIkhnjXCx/view?usp=sharing)

[Upload Image using URI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cgm6PpxjmYvpbTgj6rpgc3CPBsOxEMxP/view?usp=sharing)